# Three.js - Insert separate js file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am working with three.js right now and have a 3D cube rendered in HTML. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div id="render" class="center-block">

<script>

var camera;
var scene;
var renderer;
var mesh;
var geometry;
var material1;
var material2;
var material3;
var material4;
var material5;
var material6;
var materials;
var meshFaceMaterial;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 20, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
    scene.add(light);

    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 10);
    material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/scifiminibuilders/images/8/88/Your_Picture_Here.png/revision/latest?cb=20130507015051') } );
    material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/scifiminibuilders/images/8/88/Your_Picture_Here.png/revision/latest?cb=20130507015051') } );
    material3 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/scifiminibuilders/images/8/88/Your_Picture_Here.png/revision/latest?cb=20130507015051') } );
    material4 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/scifiminibuilders/images/8/88/Your_Picture_Here.png/revision/latest?cb=20130507015051') } );
    material5 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/scifiminibuilders/images/8/88/Your_Picture_Here.png/revision/latest?cb=20130507015051') } );
    material6 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/scifiminibuilders/images/8/88/Your_Picture_Here.png/revision/latest?cb=20130507015051') } );

    materials = [material1, material2, material3, material4, material5, material6];

    meshFaceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, meshFaceMaterial );
    mesh.position.z = -50;
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.getElementById('render').appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    render();
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    render();
}

function animate() {
    mesh.rotation.x += .016;
    mesh.rotation.y += .015;
    mesh.rotation.y += .014;

    render();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

</script>
</div>
```

There is quite too much script. I want to make a separate .js file from that, but don't know how do accomplish it with three.js. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

As I understand, the script works like a canvas tag, without entering the tag in HTML. This probably disturbs by making a separate .js file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a reference to the other .js file. You've already got a reference on your page for THREE.js, I assume. So you can just copy that and reference that second file.

```
<script src="THREE.js"></script>
<script src="other_script.js"></script>
```

And put all your extra code into other_script.js (or whatever filename you use).

Comment: Make sure the THREE reference is _before_ the other script, and the path for the second script reference is the correct location of the other js file. What happens? Any errors are thrown? What if you put a simple `console.log` at the top of the other script?

Comment: Made a mistake, forgot to put the subfolder. Now the object loads, but not in the div container. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Everything works! Was too stupid, forgot to put the subfolder! Thanks for your efforts man! :)

Answer (score -1):

You most likely need to wrap your functions in a document ready tag like this:

```
$(function(){
init();
animate();
})
```

That way the external js file has been loaded for sure before you try using the functions inside of it...  Basically it has to be available in the DOM when your functions fire.